# pydev: remote debug linux server from windows

Tags: pydev

I followed http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html and configured something like this

```
PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON = [('W:',
                             r'/path/to/app'),
                            ]
```

The translation works but has one little problem: the backslashes are not translated.

I am getting the following message:

```
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist:
/path/to/app\subpath\foo\bar.py (will have no effect)
```

How can I configure pydevd_file.utils.py so the backslashes get translated?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I set

```
eclipse_sep = '\\'
python_sep = '/'
```

in pydevd_file_utils.py